# What is \Q in Perl? Is it always necessary to use \E?

Tags: perl

I just read about `\Q` and `\E` and I am trying to fully undertand them. According to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> \Q quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until \E
>
> \E end either case modification or quoted section, think vi

So I did a couple of tests:

```
$ perl -e 'print "hello\n" if "he\\tllo" =~ /\Q\t/'
hello
$ perl -e 'print "hello\n" if "he\\tllo" =~ /\t/'
$
```

If I understand it properly, without `\Q` it does not evaluate as True because it considers `\t` as a tab.

Then I used `\E` and I see no difference:

```
$ perl -e 'print "hello\n" if "he\\tllo" =~ /\Q\t\E/'
hello
```

If I give a broader string and pattern containing both literal `\t` and a tab:

```
$ perl -e 'print "hello\n" if "he\\tl\tlo" =~ /\Q\t\E.*\t/'
hello
```

It seems to work, because it considers the first `\t` as fixed string, whereas the second `\t` is considered a tab.

So is this the way `\Q` and `\E` should be used? That is, do we enclose the "clean" strings in between `\Q` and `\E`? Is it correct to just use `\Q` if everything should be treated as literal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\E` marks the end, not just of `\Q`, but other escapes, such as `\U`. So you would use it when you need the `\Q` sequence to end. But I think you are overthinking things. `\Q` is the escape version of [`quotemeta()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
"(foobar" =~ /\Q(fo+bar/    # false, "+" gets escaped
"(foobar" =~ /\Q(\Efo+bar/  # true
```

I would not say "should be used". If you do not use `\E`, then `\Q` continues through your whole pattern.

A more tangible way to see how `\E` works is to use it with `\U`:

```
$ perl -lwe' print "\Ufoobar" '
FOOBAR
$ perl -lwe' print "\Ufoo\Ebar" '
FOObar
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like `"abc $x def"` is the same as `"abc ".$x." def"`

```
$ diff -u0 \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'$_ = "abc $x def";'     2>&1 ) \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'$_ = "abc ".$x." def";' 2>&1 ) \
      && echo "same"
same
```

`"abc \Q$x\t\E def"` is the same as `"abc ".quotemeta($x."\t")." def"`

```
$ diff -u0 \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'$_ = "abc \Q$x\t\E def";'               2>&1 ) \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'$_ = "abc ".quotemeta($x."\t")." def";' 2>&1 ) \
      && echo "same"
--- /dev/fd/63  2015-01-06 11:22:49.564061341 -0500
+++ /dev/fd/62  2015-01-06 11:22:49.564061341 -0500
@@ -7,3 +7,3 @@
-6  <2> concat[t3] sK/2
-7  <1> quotemeta[t4] sK/1
-8  <2> concat[t5] sK/2
+6  <2> concat[t4] sK/2
+7  <1> quotemeta[t5] sK/1
+8  <2> concat[t6] sK/2
@@ -11 +11 @@
-a  <2> concat[t6] sKS/2
+a  <2> concat[t7] sKS/2
```

(The difference is just an difference in the indexes in the "pad", the array where lexicals are stored.)

It can also be used in regexp literals.

```
my $exact_text = "...";
my $pat = quotemeta($exact_text);
if (/$pat/) { ... }
```

is long for

```
my $exact_text = "...";
if (/\Q$exact_text\E/) { ... }
```

`\E` can be omitted if it's at the end of the literal.

```
my $exact_text = "...";
if (/\Q$exact_text/) { ... }
```

Comment: Great, so `\Q ... \E` is the same as `quotemeta(...)`. It is not exactly what I was asking (in fact I discovered the existence of `quotemeta` from the answers of this question), but it is quite a valuable information that I guess some day I will use :) Many thanks and +1!

Comment: Added `\t` to example.

Comment: Re "It is not exactly what I was asking", You mean, I didn't answer "So is this the way `\Q` and `\E` should be used?"? Depends on what you want. If you use it to do what you want, you're using it the way it should be used.

Comment: Haha don't get me wrong :) As I am just learning some Perl, I wanted to know if `\Q` and `\E` have to go always together or not. Also, I wondered if there are other circumstances in which they can be used. That is, I wanted some canonical answer regarding the usage of `\Q` and `\E`. I said "It is not exactly what I was asking" because of your approach of showing it being like `quotemeta`, nothing else. But I probably didn't explain myself properly, so apologies for that.

Comment: I did answer that. "`\E` can be omitted if it's at the end of the literal."

Comment: I will check the answers again tomorrow, there's been a lot of good information in these answers that I have to digest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The final `\E` is not needed if nothing dangerous follows it. I'm not sure this behaviour is documented, but I've seen it many times.

It's also interesting to see how variable interpolation plays with `\Q`:

```
perl -E '$x = "lo\$"; say "hello" =~ /$x/'
1

perl -E '$x = "lo\$"; say "hello" =~ /\Q$x/'

# ^
# | empty line here.
```

See also [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta).

Comment: Pretty interesting. When you say "if nothing dangerous follows", it is always within the scope of the pattern matching `/$x/`, right?

Comment: @fedorqui, Actually, no. Inside regex literals and double-quote string literals.

Comment: @ikegami I am not very sure to understand what you mean. Could you give an example of it?